# Where have all the workers gone?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Is it just me,  or have the VIP ugnaught workers completely vanished from the game?
Is the union on strike?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not just you.  I have Android, and have played enough to see plenty of Celebrities, Big Spenders, Recruiting Officers, and the new Supply Officers, but no Workers since the updates.

Comment: Same here.  When the update first came out, some people said they were still around but, despite having played enough to the all of the Imperial Awards for the recent event... I haven't gotten a single one.

Comment: Yeah,  I'm on Android too. Get plenty of the others (Though mostly upgraders and level movers). Tried buying one randomly a couple of times,  but of course nothing came of it.

Comment: Just to note, I'm on iOS, so it seems they're missing on both.

Comment: I was unsure if the Worker is still available before this. But since the Salvage Droid event started with the latest update, I've since received some through the Cargo. Previously, I've read elsewhere that when you purchase a VIP, you still see the Worker in the mix. So he must still be around. Only really rare.